# Node switch-case command running in loop

Tags: javascript

I im using the following code to manage my server (install, reinstall, restart, shutdown etc...)

```
/* SERVER - type */
switch(server.type) {
    /* INFO - server */
    case 1:
       /* MANAGE - ssh login */
       conn.on('ready', function() {
           /* MANAGE - info */
           conn.exec('uptime && cat /proc/cpuinfo', function(err, stream) {
               stream.on('close',function(code, signal) {
                    /* MANAGE - info */
                    console.log('server info closed...');
                    conn.end();
                }).on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('server info...'+data);
                    conn.end();
                }).on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log('server error...'+err);
                    conn.end();
                })
            })
        }).connect({
                host: '192.168.1.1',
                port: '22',
                username: 'root',
                password: 'myserverpass'
        })
    })
    break;
}
```

Problem is that when this exeuctes i get from console.log correct data and after i get data it contiunues to execute in loop from beginning so i need to get only this only once:

```
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
```

and i get this:

```
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
console.log('server info...'+blablabla);
```

so how can i exit from switch when command is successfuly execute so that command does not get into loop?

I im using this to connect throught SSH on node:

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

I have previus used switch case statement and no problem executing in loop...i was thinking that ssh2 need return or conn.end() event to exit from loop?

Comment: you have a ton of async callbacks. a loop can't control those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch cases don't loop on their own. So your switch case must be inside a loop that is causing it to be run more than once. As the code loops if any cases match those cases will be triggered on each loop.

You're best bet is to put your connection into a function and call it inside you loop only if the connection has not already been made. This way you can have one simple script that handles connections and all you have to do is pass the connoection params to the function.

Comment: thanks i will try async call using function call from case